# Oracle: How to Save result of query on Unix layer

Tags: sql, unix, filesystems, oracle11g

How Can I save the result of the query onto the Unix filesystem. If its possible I need step by step process.

What I have done. 
created a directory in Unix filesystem.
created a directory in oracle pointing it towards Unix filesystem directory.

tried to spool the result to Unix filesystem But it dosent work for some reasons.

would appreciate if any 1 helps .
working on client windows xp.
Environment :oracle 11g and 
application: TOAD for oracle 11.

Comment: What the hell do you mean by "unix layer"? Sounds like a pad with UNIX logo on it...

Comment: @VladLazarenko: I think _unix layer_ might mean _a unix filesystem_. It also seems that the OP wants to save the results to a _server_ filesystem instead of a _client_ filesystem because he created an Oracle directory object.

Answer (score 1):

1st. Create the directory in Unix filesystem (not under your name otherwise it wont work ) then `chmod 777 <dir_path>` .

2nd Create a directory in oracle

```
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY <dir_name> AS '<dir_path>';
```

Now to Test it

```
create or replace procedure  WRITEFILE is
       fh UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;                                                   
       dir VARCHAR2(30) := '<dir_name>';                                                        
       name VARCHAR2(30)  := 'test1';                                                       
    begin                                                                    

       fh := UTL_FILE.FOPEN(dir, name, 'w');                                    
       UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(fh, 'bla bla');                                         
       UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(fh);
    end;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use External table unload. this will create a dump file of the query results in datapump format (you can import this file using impdp)
In order to do it create and external table who's type is ORACLE_DATAPUMP.

here is an example:

```
SQL> 
SQL> 
SQL> 
SQL> CREATE TABLE emp_ext
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL
(
 TYPE ORACLE_DATAPUMP
 DEFAULT DIRECTORY EXPORT
LOCATION ( 'emp_ext.dmp' )
 )
 AS SELECT * FROM SCOTT.EMP;  

Table created.

SQL> select count(*) from emp_ext;

  COUNT(*)
----------
        18

SQL> !ls /export/home/oracle/export     
 EMP_EXT_13392.log  emp_ext.dmp
```